# Deshabilitar que aparezca el teclado en un input

Tags: javascript, css, html5, cordova

Os comento, me encuentro con el desarrollo de una sistema en `JavaScript`, `HTML` y `CSS`. Tengo dos partes diferenciadas, un cliente de escritorio y otro cliente móvil (estoy utilizando el `framework` de `cordova` y la librería `materialize`). El caso, es que me encuentro con una duda que no encuentro. Tengo una serie de ejercicios (cada ejercicio son textos con `inputs` para completar, por ejemplo: La casa es `_erde`, pero el coche `_lanco`. Así sería completar con v y b). En el móvil, estos `inputs` se completan por medio de tags `NFC`, y no por teclado, sin embargo siempre que pulso sobre el `input` se me abre el teclado, y esto es precisamente lo que me gustaría evitar, que el teclado se abriese. Existe alguna forma para evitar esto. Adjunto aquí el código, donde me gustaría que el teclado no se abriera. Gracias a todos.

```
mostrarEjercicio:function (nombreEjercicio,textoEjercicio){

    var text=textoEjercicio;
    var textSeparado=textoEjercicio.split("@");
    var nInput=textSeparado.length-1;
    var idInput=0;
    for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      // Mostrar inputs en función de textoEjercicio
      if(text.charAt(i)=="@"){
        var inputN='<input id="'+idInput+'" type="text" style="width:20px; color:green; font-size: 26pt ">'
        text = text.replace("@", inputN);
        idInput++;
      }
    }

    var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTextoAlumno" align="center"><h3>'+ nombreEjercicio +'</h3><div class="card-panel cyan lighten-5"><h4 style="color:black;">'+ text + '</h4></div>';
    cadena=cadena+'<div align="center" id="mostrarSolucion">';
    cadena=cadena+'<button id="verBorradorBtn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Ver borrador<i class="material-icons right">edit</i></button> ';
    cadena=cadena+'</div></div>';
    $('#messageDiv').append(cadena);

    var respuestaAlumno=[];
    var respuestaAlumnoC;


    $('#verBorradorBtn').on('click',function(){
        respuestaAlumno=[];
        for (let i=0; i<idInput;i++) {
           respuestaAlumno.push($(`#${i}`).val());
        }
      ///////////////// Código por completar del onclick \\\\\\\\\\\\
    });


},
```

Answer (score 3):

Haberla, ahyla ... otra cosa es que te sirva.

Basta con establecer tu `input` como **de solo lectura**:

```
var inputN='<input id="'+idInput+'" type="text" readonly style="width:20px; color:green; font-size: 26pt ">'
```

Con eso evitarás que el móvil muestre el teclado ... pero a cambio, todas las operaciones de edición (añadir, eliminar, ...) tendrás que realizarlas tú *a mano* usando JavaScript.

Comment: Entonces, si yo escribo en el input, que lo hago, pero con el tag NFC, no me valdría? Voy a probar que tal. Gracias

Comment: Siento no poder serte de mas ayuda, pero la verdad es que ni idea. Yo lo he usado así mostrando un `keypad` al introducir contraseñas, haciéndolo todo con JavaScript. Si los `tag NFC` esos generan eventos interceptables desde JavaScript, **si** podrías usarlo.

Comment: Sí, lo acabo de probar y funciona, salvo que no sé donde estoy seleccionando, es decir, el input que pulso no hace ningún tipo de acción de que ha sido seleccionado, como si pulsara cualquier otro lado de la pantalla. Pero funcionar funciona. ¿Tal vez haya forma de que se sepa si he pulsado?. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¡ Anda ! Me alegro :-) supongo que tiene que haber alguna forma de *indicar* el `input` activo, usando `CSS` o algo ... pero la verdad es que ni idea. Me temo que tendrás que publicar otra pregunta, a ver si alguien te puede orientar en eso.